# php can't find extension even though, it's enabled in my ini file and the dll file exists

Tags: php, windows

I keep getting this error: **WARN  PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick' (tried: C:\php\ext\imagick (Kan opgegeven module niet vinden), C:\php\ext\php_imagick.dll (Kan opgegeven module niet vinden)) in Unknown on line 0.**

I'm using php 8.1.20. The ddl file for imagick that I've got from:
https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.7.0/windows does exists in my ext folder and I have added the following line in my ini file: extension=imagick

Why would I keep getting this error? Does anyone know what could be the problem?

I double checked the path of the ddl file and that's not the problem. I have dubble checked that the correct php ini file is being used.

Comment: That error message relates to a missing 'zip' extension, not imagick.  Are you sure you have this extension installed also?  (Also, please don't post images of errors - include the actual text.  It helps for future users of SO with a similar problem to find this thread)

Comment: You're right, that was a mistake on my part. I changed it to the related error.

Comment: When you download DLL files from third-parties, you need to ensure that everything matches: PHP version, processor architecture, PHP architecture, thread-safety...

Comment: I've tried both NTS and TS dll versions and still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the wrong php_imagick.dll version. This dll file was for php version 8.1.2 and I was using php version 8.1.20. I downgraded to php 8.1.2 and the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong php_imagick.dll version too... but in a different way. I got NTS version, but Thread Safety was enabled in my (Windows) environment. I only changed to TS version and the error gone.

**Note:** one can discover if thread safe is enabled typing:

> php -i|findstr "Thread"

Hope this help someone! o/